# Get the output of the last command in an interactive Julia session, like Python's underscore

Tags: julia

In a command-line Python session, you can use the underscore to grab the output of the previous expression:

```
> 5 * 6
30
> _ + 2
32
```

Is there something similar in Julia?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ans` (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#ans)

```
julia> 5 * 6
30

julia> ans + 2
32
```